# Mouse drag not working in listview.builder?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code:

```
ListView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            physics: globalScrollPhysics,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: this.results.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return SearchResultCard(
                  foodData: this.results[index],
                  constraints: this.constraints,
                  index: index);
            },
          ),
```

The globalScrollPhysics is just AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics. The problem I'm facing is that I can't seem to drag the listview to scroll with my mouse. I can use a trackpad and scroll with 2-fingers but when I use a mouse, I can't drag it. What's causing the issue? The widget is at the top of a stack so there is nothing above it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrolling by drag with a mouse has been removed on **Flutter V2.5**

For more, [Check this git thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/81569).

Comment: Is there really no way to have a Horizontal ListView be draggable ?

Comment: yes it is possible to have it,  check [on doc](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/default-scroll-behavior-drag)  and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69234580/10157127)