# Flutter NumberPicker in AlertDialog doesnt work properly

Tags: flutter

When I pick a new value with the NumberPicker, it always jumps back to the previous value and not to the current chosen value.

I am using the NumberPicker within AlertDialog and I call the NumberPicker with the pickValue() function.

```
  void pickValue() {
    showDialog<int>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Wähle eine Aufgabenanzahl"),
            content: NumberPicker(
              selectedTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
              value: currentValue,
              minValue: 1,
              maxValue: 10,
              onChanged: (value) => setState(() => currentValue = value),
            ),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                child: Text("OK", style: TextStyles.body),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              )
            ],
          );
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In This widget tree(using separate demo) you can see the `showDialog()` separated from the current context.

[image]

The use `StatefulBuilder` inside `showDialog()` or `showModalBottomSheet()`+... is these widgets are separated from current context tree.

We use `StatefulBuilder` when we like to show changes on dialogs. `StatefulBuilder` has its own `state`⇾ `builder: (BuildContext context, setState)`  and calling `setState` is using `StatefulBuilder`'s setstate.

Now let's say you want to change both UI, to do that you need to simply rename `StatefulBuilder`'s state to something  like `SBsetState` inside builder.

- to update the `_WidgetState` use `setState((){})`
- to update on dialog UI, use StatefulBuilder's state  like `SBsetState((){})`

For more,

- [StatefulBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html)
- [showDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html)
- [AlertDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html)

```
  showDialog<int>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text("Wähle eine Aufgabenanzahl"),
        content:StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (context, SBsetState) {
            return NumberPicker(
                selectedTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                value: currentValue,
                minValue: 1,
                maxValue: 10,
                onChanged: (value) { 
                setState(() => currentValue = value);// to change on widget level state 
                SBsetState(() => currentValue = value); //* to change on dialog state
                }
              );
          }
        ),
         
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            child: Text("OK", style: TextStyles.body),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          )
        ],
      );
    });
```

Comment: thank you, works fine :)

Comment: I can't scroll with mouse drag. when I move the vertical scroll bar, the numbers go too high and exceed the maxValue.

Comment: OK, that happens when I set the maxValue to be too large

Comment: @Rony Tesler Can you provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and you can find [answer about mouse drag behavior.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69232764/10157127)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Seems to work now, maybe it was a problem with the hot reload, not sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the content of the alert dialog in a `StatefulBuilder`. It will provide a new context and a setState function to rebuild the widget.

```
void pickValue() {
showDialog<int>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text("Wähle eine Aufgabenanzahl"),
        content:StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (context, setState) {
            return NumberPicker(
                selectedTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                value: currentValue,
                minValue: 1,
                maxValue: 10,
                onChanged: (value) => setState(() => currentValue = value),
              );
          }
        ),
         
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            child: Text("OK", style: TextStyles.body),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          )
        ],
      );
    });
}
```