# DropdownButton within showModalBottomSheet doesn't reflect value change

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-state, flutter-dialog

I'm trying to add a dropdown list, depending, for Android I'm using DropdownButton, for iOS a CupertinoPicker:

```
Platform.isAndroid
? AndroidSelect(
    items: ([0] + priceOptions),
    value: minPrice,
    zeroValue: 'no min',
    onChanged: (int? newVal) {
      setState(() {
        minPrice = newVal;
      });
    },
  )
: CupertinoSelect(
    initial: initialFromCupertino,
    onSelectedItemChanged: (index) {
      setState(() {
        minPrice = index == 0
            ? null
            : priceOptions[index - 1];
      });
    },
    options: priceOptionsFrom),
```

This code sits within a `showModalBottomSheet`.

The AndroidSelect is a separate stateless widget:

```
class AndroidSelect extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<int> items;

  final int? value;
  final String zeroValue;

  final void Function(int?) onChanged;
  const AndroidSelect(
      {Key? key,
      required this.items,
      required this.value,
      required this.onChanged,
      required this.zeroValue})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('building…');
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
      child: DropdownButton<int>(
        onChanged: onChanged,
        value: value ?? 0,
        items: items.map<DropdownMenuItem<int>>((int value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<int>(
            value: value,
            child: Text(
              value == 0 ? zeroValue : '$value CHF',
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now, when I change the dropdown, then the change is saved into `minPrice` (I have another widget which depends on it and this one *does* update), but the dropdown does not reflect the new value. The `print('building…')` is not called, when the `setState() {minPrice=newVal};` is executed. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return `StatefulBuilder` from `showModalBottomSheet`'s builder and use its setState to update dialog UI.

```dart
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (c) {
      return StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (context, setStateSB) {
          return SizedBox(
            width: 300,
            height: 200,
            child: AndroidSelect(
              items: [1, 2, 4, 5],
              onChanged: (v) {
                setStateSB(() {
                  value = v;
                });
              },
              value: value,
              zeroValue: "nana",
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    });
```

Comment: indeed, that works! Can you point me to some documentation why this is needed? And why was it working for the CupertinoPicker but not for the DropdownButton?

Comment: You can check [this answer about show Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69609194/10157127) and `CupertinoPicker`(extends) itself a `StatefulWidget`  and `AndroidSelect` is StatelessWidget.

Comment: I tried turning AndroidSelect into a stateful widget before but that didn't work…

Comment: I need to check that code structure before commenting on `StatefulWidget`  situation.