# Flutter PageView nor working, even on the oficial doc and example

Tags: flutter, flutter-pageview

Flutter PageView is not working properly for changing pages horinzontaly.

Even not on the oficial doc and example:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html

Its not scrolling.

Using Flutter 3.10.6 • 2023-07-12 17:57 • f468f3366c • stable

I´m using IOS. My code dos this simple thing and is not working properly.

I´m using IOS. My code dos this simple thing and is not working properly.

```
  body: ScopedBuilder<SetlistItemStore, Exception, List<SetlistItemModel>>(
        store: store,
        onLoading: (context) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
        onState: (_, setlists) {
          return PageView(
            controller: _pageController,
            children: <Widget>[_buildList(setlists), _buildSongLyrics()],
            onPageChanged: (page) {
              setState(() {
                floatVisible = (page == 0);
                _readOnlyLyrics = true;
              });
            },
          );
        },
```

Is this happening with someone else?

Trying to scroll pages with PageView

Comment: Are you using Flutter Web?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Web: Cannot scroll with mouse down (drag) (Flutter 2.5+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69232764/flutter-web-cannot-scroll-with-mouse-down-drag-flutter-2-5)

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
physics: const ScrollPhysics(parent: null),
```

into listview.builder

Comment: I´m not using a ListView